# Access violation error in Assembly Language program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I wrote a program in assembly language to perform few arithmetic operations.
I got the following error and my cmd has crashed with some big memory dump. The error was:

> First-chance exception at 0x004011c6 in Prog.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00406000. Unhandled exception at 0x004011c6 in Prog.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00406000.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
include Irvine32.inc

.data
A SDWORD ?
B SDWORD 10
C SDWORD 20
D SDWORD 30

.code
main PROC
MOV eax, B
SUB eax, C
ADD edx, D
ADD edx, 3
ADD edx, B
SUB edx, 10
SUB edx, D
SUB eax, edx
MOV A, eax

CALL DumpRegs
CALL DumpMem
exit

main ENDP
END main
```

The memory dump:

[image: cmd-output]

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.  Always post your code as text!  Please edit your post to change your picture of code into text.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.  And tell us which instruction it was that faulted.  Your dump doesn't show instruction addresses.

Comment: You are seeing the result of `DumpRegs` and `DumpMem`. As for the crash, that must therefore be due to `exit` not exiting properly.

Comment: @Jester: What memory does `DumpMem` dump?  Does it need an arg?  And will it crash if you pass it an out-of-range arg?

Comment: @PeterCordes good point. No idea.

Comment: @Jester: The text output looks like it might be a whole page of bytes, so I'm going with the theory that it's running with a size too large.

Comment: _Receives: ESI = starting offset, ECX = number of units, EBX = unit size (1=byte, 2=word, or 4=doubleword)_ You are correct as usual :D

Comment: Unhandled exception occurs at  this point in Disassembly        004011C6  mov         al,byte ptr [esi]

Comment: @fuz I am sorry. I didn't knew that.

Comment: @Naksha Thank you for your collaboration.  Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arithmetic isn't causing the crash. At the bottom you call the [Irvine32](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html) Library's [DumpRegs](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/dumpregs.htm) feature that displays the registers at the top. That is fine, but what is crashing is the call to [DumpMem](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/dumpmem.htm). It is crashing because you haven't initialized the parameters to *DumpMem* properly. You need to set the starting point, the size, and the number of values to print. The result is that it started dumping memory from an unexpected location until it failed at a memory address your program didn't have access to. That caused the access violation.

The useful thing to print would probably be the result `A` and the 3 other variables in memory after it. According to the *DumpMem* documentation:

> DumpMem PROC
>
> ```
>  Writes a range of memory to standard output in hexadecimal.
>
>  Call args:  ESI = starting offset
>              ECX = number of units
>              EBX = bytes/unit (1,2,or 4)
>
>  Return arg: None
> ```

If you want to start printing 32-bit (4 byte) SDWORDs starting at `A` and including the 3 SDWORDs after it you could modify your code to be:

```
CALL DumpRegs
MOV ESI, OFFSET A                 ; Address A is start of memory to print
MOV EBX, SIZEOF A                 ; Same as MOV EBX, 4
MOV ECX, 4                        ; Number of 32-bit SDWORDs to print
CALL DumpMem
```

---

### Code Observations

Not related to the access violation is that you have this code at the start:

```
MOV eax, B
SUB eax, C
ADD edx, D
```

When your program starts running there is no guarantee that the registers are zero. In this code you add `D` to *EDX* and store the result in *EDX*. You may have intended to simply `MOV EDX, D` instead of using ADD?

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful.

Comment: @Naksha : didnt realize until after.There was an error on the line `MOV EBX. SIZEOF A` . The period was suppose to be a comma. I fixed my answer. The original would have failed with an assembler error. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I didn't realize the mistake in my code until now. I added MOV instruction.